# Build automation - Error while running automatic build for D365F&O project using azure devops pipeline -

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package, build-automation

I have setup azure devops and trying to run automatic build through nuget package. while tunning the build step, it is throwing error

> MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist

Here is the structure of my repos

[image]

Here is the pipeline:

[image]

Here is the error:

[image]

I tried to check the pipeline parameters. but it seems correct.

Comment: You could at least add dir /s /b command before the build to see what files actually exists and where.